# How to use request configuration builder to set test device ids?

Tags: flutter, admob

On emulator while testing I've got a message in console

> Use
> RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("alphaNumericString"))
> to get test ads on this device.

Where and how apply this code in app?

Comment: There is a testIds property in some class from the google_mobile_ads package. I’m not sure in which one, maybe it’s the one you construct the ad with.